# How to make divs stack on top of each other as page is minimized

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make a section of divs on my page responsive so that as the page is minimized, the divs begin stacking on top of each other. I've tried `flex-direction: column` but that doesn't seem to be working. I have attached photos of what I am trying to achieve.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <!-- <section> -->
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item3">
        <image-tag src="https://></image-tag>
      </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <image-tag src="https://></image-tag>
      </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <image-tag src="https://></image-tag>
      </div>
      <div class="item3 idk">
        <image-tag src="https://></image-tag>
      </div>
      <div class="item3 idk">
        <image-tag src="https://></image-tag>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
  <!-- </section> -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Photos of what I am trying to achieve

Desktop

[image: Desktop]

Tablet

[image: Tablet]

Mobile

[image: Mobile]

FYI I have taken some code out for confidentiality purposes.

Answer (score 1):

try `flex-wrap: wrap;`

use `.item3{ flex: 1 }` if needed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this does not seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

A flex-box solution is hard because it is meant for 1 directional layouts where as your desired layout is 2 directional based on screen width. However, you can come close to the desired layout behavior by using flex-wrap which depends on either the width of your flex-items or flex-container to force the items to a new line. Try the below and adjust either the items' or container's width

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `max-width: 1200px;` to your body element then
`margin:0 auto` to center vertically.

Than create a flexbox inside container class and make `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make flexbox create new row else all the images will always stay in same row.

You can also add `padding: 0 1rem;` for always having empty spaces when images comes to limit of wrapping.

```css
/* RESET */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* RESET ENDS */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x375" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x375" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x375" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x375" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x375" alt="" />
      </div>
</div>
```